# static_assert doesn't recognize a const char* template parameter as constexpr: g++ bug?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr, static-assert

Consider the definitions below.

```
char right_string[]="::right_one.";
char wrong_string[]="::wrong_one.";

template<const char* str>
void f(){
    static_assert(str==::right_string, "Pass me ::right_string!");
}

struct Test{

    static constexpr char right_string[]="template_struct::right_one";
    static constexpr char wrong_string[]="template_struct::wrong_one";

    template<const char* str>
    static void f(){
        static_assert(str==right_string, "Pass me template_struct::right_string!");
    }

};

int main(){
    f< ::right_string>();           //compiles, as expected
    f< ::wrong_string>();           //does not compile, as expected
    Test::f<Test::right_string>();  //compiles, as expected
    Test::f<Test::wrong_string>();  //error in Test::f: non-constant condition for static assertion
}
```

The complete error is

> ../main.cpp:16:3: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
>
> ../main.cpp:16:3: error: ‘(((const char*)(& Test::wrong_string)) == ((const char*)(& Test::right_string)))’ is not a constant expression

I believe that this is a compiler bug, because it doesn't make sense that the `constexpr`ness of the expression within `static_assert` changes according to what I pass as a template parameter (whether `Test::right_string` or `Test::right_string`).

I have already found that g++ 4.6 is [somewhat flawed](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53009) when handling addresses as template parameters. Is this an instance of the same bug?

Comment: The `static_assert`s work on g++ 4.7.

Comment: I have filed a bug http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53181

Comment: @Lorenzo : If it's already fixed in a new version, why bother filing a bug for the old version?

Comment: @ildjarn Because when I filed it I didn't receive any comment yet. And because they seem to update older release series. For example, 4.5.1 is of Jul 31 2010, but 4.4.5 dates October 1 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a g++ bug, fixed (at least) in 4.7.